# How to implement bagging for a proportional odds model

Tags: r

In R, I have built a proportional odds model for a data set, and now want to implement bagging for prediction based on this proportional odds model. The ultimate goal is to generate a set of outputs in my testing data and compare with the original model I built, to see if the bagging improved the prediction.

I cannot find anywhere how to do this specifically, but here is what I have found (code adapted from https://www.r-bloggers.com/improve-predictive-performance-in-r-with-bagging/). I always get an error message regarding the `%do%` command, and when I eliminate this I get an error in trying to execute `rowMeans(predictions)`. Any suggestions?

```
library(foreach)
library(MASS)
length_divisor <- 4
iterations <- 1000

predictions <- foreach(m=1:iterations, .combine=cbind) %do%
{
  training_positions <- sample(nrow(new.training),
    size=floor((nrow(new.training)/length_divisor)))

  train_pos <- 1:nrow(new.training) %in% training_positions

  polr_fit <- polr(as.factor(quality) ~ ., 
    data=training[train_pos,], Hess=TRUE)

  predict(polr_fit, newdata=new.testing)
}

predictions <- rowMeans(predictions)
predictions
```

Comment: Please provide exactly what the error message says in your question.

Comment: Error in { : task 1 failed - "response must have 3 or more levels"

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Thanks!